# Count Distinct XML Pattern in Notepad++ or in Linux Grep

Tags: linux, notepad++

Its a  silly question, but I can't find the answer yet.

In my XML i've got the below lines:

```
<BLAH><BLAH><BLAH>
<ABC>123456</ABC>
<ABC>123456</ABC>
<ABC>adfadfaf</ABC>
<ABC>gdsgdhghd</ABC>
</BLAH></BLAH></BLAH>
```

Distinct count of patterns in `<ABC>*</ABC>` is 3.

Basically I want to count unique values between `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` 3  when I do a find & count in notepad++ or in Linux grep command.

Comment: Using `grep` or similar tools to process XML is problematic. It will not work in all cases, except if your XML input follows some restrictions that are not required by XML or the document specification. Do you want to count the number of unique text content values between `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` tags? Does every pair of `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` tags appear on its own line without any additional tags as in your example? Please [edit] your question and add more details, don't answer in comments.

Comment: Yes indeed, updated my question. @Bodo

Comment: Please confirm in your question: Does every pair of `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` tags appear on its own line without any additional tags as in your example? Can the corresponding `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` tags be on separate lines?

Comment: every pair of the tag appears on it own line, but your answer would help in future if there are any changes. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input has a format as shown in the example, you can use the code below.

That means every combination of corresponding `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` tags must be in one line with a text-only value in between.

```
grep -o '<ABC>[^<]*</ABC>' input.xml |sort -u|wc -l
```

The command may not work if the input is formatted in other ways or if the value between `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` contains other tags.

With the example input from the question it will print

```
3
```

It even works when there is more than one pair of `<ABC>` and `</ABC>` in a line.

With

```
<BLAH><BLAH><BLAH>
<ABC>123456</ABC>foo<ABC>1234567</ABC>
<ABC>123456</ABC>
<ABC>adfadfaf</ABC>
<ABC>gdsgdhghd</ABC>
</BLAH></BLAH></BLAH>
```

it prints

```
4
```

Comment: "sort -u" is not working on Linux emulator (cmder), but works on linux terminal is there way to get around this?

Comment: @Naga What exactly means "is not working"? Do you get an error message or output different from what you expect? According to https://cmder.net/, `cmder` is a console emulation, not a "Linux emulation". You might have to install a shell (e.g. `bash`) or the `sort` command. How to solve the problem with `sort -u` in `cmder` should be asked as separate question as this is only slightly related to your original question.

Comment: linux emulator has limited functionality, I was able to run it in the linux server itself without any issues.

Comment: Good that you found a workaround by running the command on a Linux system. If you don't tell what "is not working" means by showing the exact error message or expected vs actual result, we cannot help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will **only** work if the `<ABC>...</ABC>` is ordered.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(<ABC>.+?</ABC>)\R(?!\1)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Count</kbd>

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this regex helps in getting the total count, but did not work fetching unique count of records within <ABC> and </ABC>